# AudioKit errors out only on real device

Tags: swift, avfoundation, viewcontroller, audiokit

When I try to run my app on a real device I get the following error:

"...AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:2054:InstallTapOnNode: (err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInInputChain(ThisGraph, *inputNode)): error -10868

...*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10868'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException] "

The error happens when I try to start my Audio engine, the only code that gets executed before that is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addNavBarImage()
    print("init started ")
    guard let input = engine.input else { fatalError() }

    guard let device = engine.inputDevice else { fatalError() }
    initialDevice = device
    mic = input
    tappableNodeA = Fader(mic)
    print("input selected")
    mixer = Mixer(arpeggioSynthesizer, padSynthesizer, bassSynthesizer, drumKit)
    filter = MoogLadder(mixer)
    filter?.cutoffFrequency = 20_000
    engine.output = filter
  
    
    print("objects init")
    tracker = PitchTap(mic) { pitch, amp in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.update(pitch[0], amp[0])
        }
    }
    print("objects init finished")
    start() <-  this is the point where the code errors out, its just the try function to start the engine.
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Error `-10868` is `kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported`. Make of that what you will.